# Exact matching on >= 1 variable and fuzzy matching on >=1 variable stata

Tags: merge, match, stata

In Stata, how can I do exact matching on at least one variable as well as fuzzy matching on at least one variable?

For instance, say that I want to do exact matching on `org` and `year` and fuzzy matching on `firstname` and `lastname`. In other words, in order for it to even consider fuzzy matching on `firstname` and `lastname`, `org` and `year` must be exact matches.

Here is an example dataset:

```
*dataset a
clear all
input str1 org year str10 firstname str12 lastname
"A" 2010 "susan" "robertson"
"A" 2011 "bob" "miller"
"B" 2010 "albert" "smith"
"B" 2011 "sue" "washington"
end
tempfile a
save `a'
```

And the other one, to be merged:

```
*dataset b
clear all
input str1 org year str10 firstname str12 lastname
"A" 2010 "Susan A" "Robertson"
"A" 2011 "bob" "Miller"
"A" 2012 "francisco" "ramirez"
"B" 2010 "mike" "doorpen"
"B" 2011 "sue h" "washnngton"
end
tempfile b
save `b'
```

How can I accomplish what I want?

The best I can think of is to use `matchit` after combining `firstname` and `lastname` together into one variable, say `name`. Then keep only the fuzzy matched results above some threshold for the observations that have the same `org` and `year`. But this seems pretty clunky. Is there a better way? Open to all approaches.

Comment: The "clunkiness" is particularly strong when the number of unneeded matches is high. For example when there are lots of years and organisations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone told me the answer on Twitter: use `reclink` (https://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/r/reclink.html) with the `required` option.